# Is it possible to identify the application performing an API call?

Tags: spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0, api-gateway

I have a single page application (VueJs) that interacts with my API (spring-web).

Through the authentication (spring-security-OAuth) I can know "who", which user, performs API call.

What I would like to know is, "what application did that user used to issue his call ? Mine or his ?"

I don't want to prevent my user to write their own application against my API, on the contrary but I'd like to be able to identify these "external" applications, gather usage statistics and apply rate limiting.

However I can't think of a reliable way to do so. If someone writes a script that mimics a user authenticating through the login page, he will get everything (token, cookies, ...) that will make my API-Gateway think the request comes from "My application".

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: How about using the referer header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer ?

Comment: @MarekPuchalski I did not know about "forbidden header" but I think it will not do the trick as - correct me if I'm wrong - a backend/mobile application has full control of the headers, even "forbidden ones"

Comment: Yes, backend/mobile applications will have complete control over every aspect of the HTML payload. The best thing you have is the referer header though. If you decide not to trust it at all, then you can not really solve this issue, as the whole HTML payload may be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the username and password should not be available to any other person other than your application user.

But if you still want to know the application that is making the call you can create an custom HEADER which you can pass with each request and log the data back, if you want you can also block any request using the spring security filters that are not containing that custom HEADER.

The logging will only work if you are providing in your API documentation to pass the Application Name Value in that Specific HEADER to your 3rd Party API consumers.

Comment: User and applications are not the same thing fore me. Users are individuals using "my application" with their own login/pwd. (N user <-> 1 Application) but the same individual with the same login/pwd could also access the API directly (not through "my application") or even create say an Android/IOs App that all other user could use with their login/pass.

Using header is not reliable enough as the user who already has access to the API through "my application" can simply open the dev console (F12) and he will see all headers passed in requests.

Comment: You can use AES encryption to send and receive value in the header such that the data you are passing is encrypted and decrypted using some secret that only you know

Comment: Encryption will only hide the actual value to the user but if he simply copies the encrypted value and put it is his header, my service will still believe it's coming from my application.

Comment: You can use HTTPS connection with a certificate and a public key combo, sign every req coming from your UI (certificate and a public key) don't store it in code rather keep the files on server and give the 3rd party the same certificate and public key to use with every request and keep the private key on backend to verify that. In this way may the user see the request contents but will never have the certificate+public key hence, his req will be denied by your backend.